# ERROR: Failed to build linux

Tags: linux, configure

While compiling linux, I get following error:

```
[ALL  ]   CC      drivers/usb/otg/ulpi_viewport.o
[ALL  ]   LD      drivers/usb/phy/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   LD      drivers/usb/storage/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   CC      drivers/usb/usb-common.o
[ALL  ]   LD      drivers/usb/otg/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   LD      drivers/usb/host/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   LD      drivers/usb/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   LD      drivers/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   LINK    vmlinux
[ALL  ]   LD      vmlinux.o
[ALL  ]   MODPOST vmlinux.o
[WARN ] WARNING: modpost: Found 1 section mismatch(es).
[ALL  ] To see full details build your kernel with:
[ALL  ] 'make CONFIG_DEBUG_SECTION_MISMATCH=y'
[ALL  ]   GEN     .version
[ALL  ]   CHK     include/generated/compile.h
[ALL  ]   UPD     include/generated/compile.h
[ALL  ]   CC      init/version.o
[ALL  ]   LD      init/built-in.o
[ALL  ]   LD      vmlinux
[ALL  ] `xemacps_remove' referenced in section `.data' of drivers/built-in.o: defined in discarded section `.exit.text' of drivers/built-in.o
[ALL  ] `xwdtps_remove' referenced in section `.data' of drivers/built-in.o: defined in discarded section `.exit.text' of drivers/built-in.o
[ERROR] make[3]: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
[ERROR] make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
[ALL  ] make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/suheb/New/petalinux-v2013.10-final/components/linux-kernel/xlnx-3.8'
[ERROR] make[1]: *** [/home/bacup_5april/Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/kernel/xlnx-3.8/vmlinux] Error 2
[ALL  ] make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bacup_5april/Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux/kernel'
[ALL  ] make: *** [sub_build_component_/kernel/linux-kernel/single/xlnx-3.8] Error 2
[ALL  ] make: Leaving directory `/home/bacup_5april/Xilinx-ZC702-14.7/build/linux'
ERROR: Failed to build linux
```

It is not giving clear idea of what is wrong ? This error started coming when I made some chnages in configuration fof kernel (specifically removed SMP support )

Comment: How did you make these configuration changes?  You may want to run `make clean` before you do the build, but backup your `.config` first (can't remember whether `clean` removes this or not).

Comment: You should contact Xilinx for support about their crappy out-of-tree Ethernet driver. But of course it would be better to get rid of it.